# Show $f$ is injective in $B$, that $f|_B^{-1}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V$ and $W$ be normed spaces of the same dimension. Let $U \subseteq V$ be an open set and $f : U \rightarrow W$ a $C^1$ mapping. Suppose that $a \in U$ and that $(Df)_a$ is invertible. Produce a ball $B = \{x : |x-a| < \delta\} \subseteq U$ and a number $\alpha>0$ such that $|f(q)-f(p)|\ge \alpha |q-p|$ for all $q,p\in B$. Conclude that $f$ is injective in $B$, that $f|_B^{-1}$ is continuous, and that $(Df)_x$ is invertible for all $x \in B$.

So assuming I find such $\delta$ and $\alpha$, how Do I know that $f$ is injective in $B$, that $f|_B^{-1}$ is continuous, and that $(Df)_x$ is invertible for all $x \in B$?

Comment: Are $V, W$ finite dimensional?

Comment: Yes I believe so

Comment: Use mean value theorem on $f(q)-f(p)$ and take $\alpha = \| Df_a^{-1} \|^{-1}$. The set of invertible matrices is open. Finally, the inverse function theorem yields rest.

Comment: Oh $\alpha < \| Df_a^{-1} \|^{-1} \|$. My bad.